# Use of wildcards on nested generic type like CompletableFuture<List<? extends Something>>

Tags: java, generics

This works (compiles and runs no problem):

```
List<? extends CharSequence> strings = null;
List<CharSequence> realStrings = new ArrayList<>();
strings = realStrings;
```

But this very similar piece of code doesn't:

```
CompletableFuture<List<? extends CharSequence>> strings = null;
CompletableFuture<List<CharSequence>> realStrings = 
   CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ArrayList<>());
strings = realStrings; // <--- ERROR
```

The error I'm getting there is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from CompletableFuture<List<CharSequence>> to CompletableFuture<List<? extends CharSequence>>`

This doesn't make much sense to me. Why is it fine to assign 'realStrings' to 'strings' in the first example but not the second?

PS: In case it matters. Compiling with Java 8.

Comment: is this related to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Maybe, although, if it is I'd still like to get a clear explanation how it applies to my example(s) with the wildcards.

Comment: I've answered this kind of question a bunch of times. It's hard to find a good duplicate though, since the per case explanation differs. But that linked question is _a_ dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Generics are invariant*. That means that if you declare the type `CompletableFuture<List<? extends CharSequence>>` you can only assign another `CompletableFuture` to it if it's type parameter matches *exactly*.

This behaviour can be changed with bounded wildcards, like you show in your first snippet. You can assign a `List<CharSequence>` to a `List<? extends CharSequence>`.

You'd have to duplicate that with the `CompletableFuture`. i.e. You could assign a `CompletableFuture<T>` to a `CompletableFuture<? extends T>`. If `T = List<CharSequence>`, then you'd get `CompletableFuture<? extends List<CharSequence>>`. But since in this case `List` is also a generic type, you can again apply wildcards to get `CompletableFuture<? extends List<? extends CharSequence>>`:

```
CompletableFuture<? extends List<? extends CharSequence>> strings = null;
CompletableFuture<List<CharSequence>> realStrings = 
    CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ArrayList<>());
strings = realStrings; // <--- WORKS!
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a bit hard to wrap one's head around, but basically it has to do with whether any operation you can expect to be allowed to perform through a reference would be unsupportable with the supplied instance.

Looking at the general problem, if I have a class

```
class Foo<T> {
    public T getT() { /* ... */ }
    public void setT(T t) { /* ... */ }
}
```

and then I say

```
Foo<List<? extends Bar>> myFoo;
```

anyone with this reference must be able to perform the operations

```
List<? extends Bar> myList = myFoo.getT();
```

and

```
List<? extends Bar> myList;
myFoo.setT(myList);
```

Now can a `Foo<List<Bar>>` support that?  Well... no.  A `Foo<List<Bar>>` is allowed to know that it's `setT` receives a `List<Bar>`, which is not the same as a `List<? extends Bar>`.  When you pass a `List` to `setT`, it could pass a `Bar` to that `List`'s `.add()`; but if the `List` is a `List<Frob>` (where `Frob` extends `Bar`, so that `List<Frob>` is a valid `List<? extends Bar>`) then it won't be able to handle that.

So that's why your 2nd code snippet doesn't work.  Why doesn't it apply to the first one?  Well, the analysis is different.  In that first case, it is perfectly true that a `List<B>` is an example of a `List<? extends B>`